# Create SQL Script for Statistics

Tags: sql-server

I wanna create script my whole table, including all statistics and indexes.

In SSM, When I right click table and create script, it gives me script for Indexes for not for statistics.

If I right click indexes, then there is an option to generate script, but this option is disabled when I right click Statistics.

Can anyone tell me how do I generate script for statistics.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SSMS, open Tools -> Options and go to the "SQL Server Object Explorer" item in the left-hand pane. Expand that and you should see a "Scripting" subitem. From there, navigate to the "Table and View Options" section and you should see an option to say whether statistics are scripted or not.